# jQuery: Slide Toggle || Any optimizations to the code?

Tags: jquery, optimization, toggle, slide

Hi Im new to programming jQuery and i have a quick code snippet that I would love someone to test for me.

I think it works well.. but i dont know if its the best way to handle it.

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zWnLv/29/

```
//hide wrapper at document ready
        $('#newsbox_content_wrapper').hide();

        //toggle visiblility of newsbox and slide down to scroll window to newsbox
        $('.newsbox_toggle').bind('click', function () {
            //define speed for effect
            var $speed = 400;

            //check to see if the class 'open' exists then run
            if ($('.newsbox_toggle').hasClass('open')) {
                //scroll to the top of the newsbox
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#header_lower').offset().top}, $speed);
                $('#newsbox_content_wrapper').slideDown($speed);
                $('.newsbox_toggle').removeClass('open');
                //delay HTML replacement to sync with animation
                $('.newsbox_expand').delay($speed).queue(function(n) {
                    $(this).html('Click to Close News Feature.');
                    $(this).addClass('rotate');
                    n();
                });
            } else {
                //scroll back to top of body
                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, $speed);
                $('#newsbox_content_wrapper').slideUp($speed);
                $('.newsbox_toggle').addClass('open');
                //delay HTML replacement to sync with animation
                $('.newsbox_expand').delay($speed).queue(function(n) {
                     $(this).html('Click to Read More.');
                     $(this).removeClass('rotate');
                     n();
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you could "optimize" this is using callbacks instead of manually delaying functions. `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` accept callbacks to be executed after the animation finishes.
Using chaining is a best practice, so you don't have to recreate objects (see the callback functions).

Also, I've changed the `bind()` function with the new `on()`, which was added in jQuery 1.7.

```
$('.newsbox_toggle').on('click', function () {
    //define speed for effect
    var $speed = 400;

    //check to see if the class 'open' exists then run
    if ($('.newsbox_toggle').hasClass('open')) {
        //scroll to the top of the newsbox
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#header_lower').offset().top}, $speed);
        $('#newsbox_content_wrapper').slideDown($speed, function() {
            $('.newsbox_expand').html('Click to Close News Feature.').addClass('rotate');
        });
        $('.newsbox_toggle').removeClass('open');
    } else {
        //scroll back to top of body
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, $speed);
        $('#newsbox_content_wrapper').slideUp($speed, function() {
            $('.newsbox_expand').html('Click to Read More.').removeClass('rotate');
        });
        $('.newsbox_toggle').addClass('open');
    }
});
```

If you're on jQuery < 1.7, use `.click()`, which is a shorthand for `.bind()`.

```
$('.newsbox_toggle').click(function () {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response to this. Like I said, im new to this, and chaining seems like the best fit for what i would like to accomplish. If i understand this correctly, the `.html` will run after the `.slideUp` has completed?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. The (anonymous) function you pass to `.slideUp` will be executed after the animation completes. Almost every jQuery animation method supports callbacks :)

Comment: Thank you so much. You have been very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go (with scroll): http://jsfiddle.net/zWnLv/43/

```
//hide wrapper at document ready and put in var for re-use
var newsbox = $('#newsbox_content_wrapper').hide();

//toggle visiblility of newsbox and slide down to scroll window to newsbox
$('.newsbox_toggle').bind('click', function() {   
    newsbox.slideToggle("slow",function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: newsbox.offset().top }, 'slow');
    });

});
```

As far as the "click to read more" you have plenty of options... you could toggle the text each time or, my preference, toggle a class with a +/- (or arrows) background image to let a user intuitively know they can open or close that section.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. The problem is the toggled div is ~450 px from the top and when it expands, it expands below the fold. Thats  why i added the additional code to scroll down to the div.

Comment: @mnelson7982 - added the scroll (see above code or go to http://jsfiddle.net/zWnLv/43/ ) - cheers

Comment: I'd like to keep the text and also use the background. The Rotate class uses CSS3 Tranform to rotate a background image that was omitted from the jsFiddle code.